# How to connect to a local database through the internet using a browser from a different computer?

Tags: c#, php, mysql

I have a desktop application in C# which has a local MySQL database and also created a simple web page using php that displays records from my local database which should be accessed from a mobile phone or any other computer via internet. How can i be able to setup the connection in my php program? Do i need to just provide the IP address of my PC and put it in my php script in the connection string?

Comment: firstly: desktop apps make *terrible* web-servers - and you usually don't want to expose a desktop OS directly to the web like that for security reasons; it would be better to design the app that serves the web page *as a server app*. Next up: is the server app visible to the internet? it isn't usually enough to just know the IP, as there are firewall, routing, NAT, etc issues to contend with

Comment: Remember, PHP runs on the server, so your connection to the local PC from PHP does not need to change

Comment: If you access your DB using a network (LAN, internet...) then it's not a *local* DB, but a remote one. You might want to open ports in your router and and set it up to be available on the web.

Comment: To avoid **many** issues (security, electricity bill that will greatly increase if your server runs 24/7...) I **strongly** advice you to get a DB host on the internet. There is plenty of cheap/free hosts

Comment: Desktop OS: Not enough external connections allowed to be any use as a real web server. PortForwarding your Router: A security risk if you dont know what you are doing. Punching hole in Firewall: Also a security risk

Comment: I'm maybe dumb or have missed something, but he didn't mention he is using that desktop app as web server, did he ?

Comment: @Cid *"I have a desktop application in C# which has a local MySQL database ..."*

Comment: @JayBlanchard to me, this means *a desktop application that communicate with a DB hosted on my computer*, not an *a desktop application with an embeded DB*, because he is using another php application to communicate with that DB. But I might be wrong.

Comment: Either way @Cid, the question is far too broad and shows no effort on the part of the OP.

Comment: This is just a testing phase as of the moment.. I'm planning to put the database to a server. So i just need to open ports in my php app? My C# app is for workstation while i  have seperate php app for web and mobile but will connected to the same database.